# How to create context in android.content.Context and android.app.Activity?

Tags: android, twitter

I try to access information from Twitter and I followed this link:

http://code.google.com/p/sociallib/wiki/SocialLibGuide

I don't understand the following two lines and it shows error in the following lines.

```
        twitter.requestAuthorization(this);
        twitter.authorize(this);
```

Full code is added below.

It says that anroid.content.Context and android.app.Activity is required. I really don't know how to add them. Any help is appreciated.

```
package sociallibjar;

import android.R;
import android.content.Context;
import com.expertiseandroid.lib.sociallib.connectors.SocialNetworkHelper;
import com.expertiseandroid.lib.sociallib.connectors.TwitterConnector;
import com.expertiseandroid.lib.sociallib.model.twitter.TwitterUser;
import org.scribe.oauth.Token;

public class TwitterApp {

    String CONS_KEY = "";
    String CONS_SEC = "";
    String CALLBACK = "";

    public void twiter() {
        try {
            TwitterConnector twitter = SocialNetworkHelper.createTwitterConnector(CONS_KEY, CONS_SEC, CALLBACK);
            twitter.requestAuthorization(this);
            twitter.authorize(this);
            Token at = twitter.getAccessToken();
            String token = at.getToken(); //You can store these two strings
            String secret = at.getSecret();//in order to build the token back


            Token myAccessToken = new Token(token, secret);
            twitter.authentify(myAccessToken);
            TwitterUser me = twitter.getUser(); //Retrieves the current user
            String nickname = me.getUsername(); //Some information is available through method calls
            int nbFollowers = me.nbFollowers; //Some is available through object fields

            System.out.println("You are logged in as " + nickname + " and you have " + nbFollowers + " followers"); //Now we can print the information we retrieved onscreen

            twitter.tweet("Tweeting from code"); //A simple tweet

            twitter.tweet("I have " + twitter.getUser().nbFollowers + " followers!");//A more elaborate tweet
            //twitter.logout(this); //Providing this code is located in an Activity (or Context) class


        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Please show a bit more code, like where are these two lines are written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation from that link it is pretty clear. For the lines:

```
twitter.requestAuthorization(this); //Providing this code is located in an Activity (or Context) class
twitter.authorize(this);
```

`this` represents a `Context`(an `Activity` for example).
Now, because your class `TwitterApp` doesn't extend `Activity` you'll need a reference to `Context` to provide to those methods. For this you could, for example, add a constructor to your `TwitterApp` class that takes a `Context`:

```
private Context ctx; //-<field in the TwitterApp class

public TwitterApp (Context ctx) {
   this.ctx = ctx;
}
```

and then you use that context for those methods:

```
twitter.requestAuthorization(ctx);
twitter.authorize(ctx);
```

In your activity where you instantiate the `TwitterApp` class just pass `this`:

```
TwitterApp obj = new TwitterApp(this);
```

Comment: Thanks slukian, Can we execute the program outside android ? because i get the following exception when i try to execute the program.                                                                       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
        at android.content.Context.<init>(Context.java:4)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.<init>(ContextWrapper.java:5)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.<init>(ContextThemeWrapper.java:5)
        at android.app.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:6)
        at sociallibjar.TwitterApp.<init>(TwitterApp.java:19)

Comment: @Bradan I don't know exactly what you mean by "outside android" but  the answer is no. You are using a library design for android so it needs a reference to the android system in the form of `Context`.

Comment: @Bradan In that case, no you can't use this library. Try to find a social java library that could be used , at a quick search i found https://code.google.com/p/opensocial-java-client/ , maybe is something to look at. Also if my answer helped you please upvote it and marked as correct :)